# Scrolling down teleports my player pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am having a problem whenever I have my scrolling for up and down for my player and I go on high ground and then jump down with my player it will glitch my collision logic. I am not sure why it's doing it.

Her's a video for example: [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/1dfa34f8cc4934eee85dd6ce562cd5d4)

As you can see, I am on high ground then when I jump down for some reason I glitch everywhere.

My scrolling up/down I made it so when my player `y` is at 50 it should scroll my player up and when my player is at 550 it should scroll my player down with the fall speed of my player, but whenever I have this code in my main loop it will cause a glitch with my collideable rects even though I made my collisions for all sides to stop the player.

The collides are the rect the player will be colliding with.

```
if playerman.y > 550:
    for obj in object_list:
        obj.y -= playerman.fall
    for shot in shots:
        shot.y -= playerman.fall
    
    for collid in collids:
        collid.y -= playerman.fall
    tall11.y -= playerman.fall



if playerman.y < 50:
    for obj in object_list:
        obj.y += playerman.speed

    for shot in shots:
        shot.y += playerman.speed
    
    for collid in collids:
        collid.y += playerman.speed

    tall11.y += playerman.speed
```

My collisions part  up down left and right for the player

```
    platform_rect_list = [p.rect for p in collids]
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)


        
    playerman.y = py
    if player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) < 0:
        playerman.x = px
        
    move_right = keys[pygame.K_d]
    move_left = keys[pygame.K_a]
    if move_right:
        for obj in object_list:
            obj.x -= playerman.speed
        for shot in shots:
            shot.x -= playerman.speed
        
        for collid in collids:
            collid.x -= playerman.speed

        tall11.x -= playerman.speed

        
    if move_left:
        for obj in object_list:
            obj.x += playerman.speed


        for shot in shots:
            shot.x += playerman.speed
        for collid in collids:
            collid.x += playerman.speed

        tall11.x += playerman.speed



    platform_rect_list = [p.get_rect() for p in collids] # get_rect()
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)

    playerman.y = py
    cI = player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list)
    if cI >= 0:
        # undo movement of platforms dependent on the direction and intersection distance
        dx = 0
        if move_right: 
            dx = platform_rect_list[cI].left - player_rect.right
        if move_left:
            dx = platform_rect_list[cI].right - player_rect.left
        for collid in collids:
            collid.x -= dx
            collid.get_rect()
        base1.x -= dx
        base2.x -= dx
        base3.x -= dx
        base4.x -= dx
        base5.x -= dx
        base6.x -= dx
        crate1.x -= dx
        base44.x -= dx
        end1.x -= dx
        base45.x -= dx
        stopmove1.x -= dx
        text_show_collision.x -= dx
        text1.x -= dx
        rop1.x -= dx
        text22.x -= dx
        text_show_collision2.x -= dx
        portal1.x -= dx
        base46.x -= dx
        tall11.x -= dx

        for shot in shots:
            shot.x -= dx



    if not playerman.isJump:  
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 0.5
        playerman.isJump = False


    # For player to get on top of platform
        collide = False
        for collid in collids:
            if playerman.get_rect().colliderect(collid.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.JumpCount = 10
                right = True
                left = True
                playerman.y = collid.rect.top - playerman.height
                if playerman.rect.right > collid.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < collid.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = collid.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < collid.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > collid.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = collid.rect.right

                if playerman.direction == "jump":
                    playerman.direction = "Idle"
                    
                if playerman.direction == "jump2":
                    playerman.direction = "leftid"

                        



        if collide:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.fall = 1
            

        # Player jumping
        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
                right = False
                left = False
            playerman.fall = 0

    ##  playerman.isJump = False  <--  omit this line.  already False
        # What will happen when player jumps
    else:

        collideBottom = False
        for collid in collids:
            if (playerman.get_rect().colliderect(collid.rect) and 
                playerman.y + playerman.height > collid.rect.bottom):
                
                collideBottom = True
                playerman.y = collid.rect.bottom
                break

        if not collideBottom and playerman.JumpCount >= 0:    
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
            if playerman.direction == "right" or playerman.direction == "Idle":
                playerman.direction = "jump"

            if playerman.direction == "left" or playerman.direction == "leftid":
                playerman.direction = "jump2"




        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10


    # redrawing the window
    redraw()

    # updating the game
    pygame.display.update()
# quiting the game
pygame.quit()
```

You can run and test this with rects no images it works the same way jump on top of the the platforms that are on the sky and then jump down and you will start glitching for some reason even though the collisions work for both sides.

[Full script](https://pastebin.com/CCcAv3Hm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to scroll you need to scroll the player, too. To avoid problems with floating point accuracy, use the integral y coordinate of the player rectangle to check if you need to scroll:

```py
if playerman.get_rect().y > 550:
    
    # scroll objects ...
    for obj in object_list:
        obj.y -= playerman.speed
    for shot in shots:
        shot.y -= playerman.speed
    for collid in collids:
        collid.y -= playerman.speed
    tall11.y -= playerman.speed
    
    # ... and scroll player
    playerman.y -= playerman.speed
    py -= playerman.speed
```

You may want to scroll with the amount of `playerman.y - 550` instead of `playerman.speed`:

```py
if playerman.get_rect().y > 550:
    scroll_offset = playerman.y - 550

    # scroll objects ...
    for obj in object_list:
        obj.y -= scroll_offset
    for shot in shots:
        shot.y -= scroll_offset
    for collid in collids:
        collid.y -= scroll_offset
    tall11.y -= scroll_offset

    # ... and scroll player
    playerman.y -= scroll_offset
    py -= scroll_offset
```

---

If you do the collision test, then you actually use the `rect` attribute of the `collide` objects:

> ```py
> platform_rect_list = [p.rect  for p in collids]
> ```

However, you have changed the `x` and `y` attribute of the `collide` objects right before. Hence the `rect` attribute doesn't reflect the current position of the objects. You must update the `rect` attributes prior to the collision test:

Fortunately, you've implemented the `get_rect()` method, which updates and returns the `rect` attribute:

> ```py
> class collid:
>    # [...]
>
>    def get_rect(self):
>        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
>        return self.rect
> ```

Call `get_rect()` instead of using the `rect` attribute directly:

<s>`platform_rect_list = [p.rect  for p in collids]`</s>

```py
platform_rect_list = [p.get_rect()  for p in collids]

player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
player_rect.topleft = (px, py)

playerman.y = py
if player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) < 0:
    playerman.x = px
```

Comment: I dont know what I would do without you man!!! always helping I got it working

Comment: can I do the same thing for my conveyor? [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/ddc00167d65f2a20bcc6121847693e04) when ever I move when its moving it will teleport my player down other then that everything is working fINE!!! [script](https://pastebin.com/50z5X6tg) < how my coneyor moves script